# DF of a given Lowess function

Tags: statistics, smoothing, loess

I understand the concept of lowess smooth, but I’m not sure how to find the degree of freedom. What is the correct way to calculate its DF?

DF are the maximum number of independent values that can vary in a sample space. It is generally calculated when we subtract one from the given sample of data. Is it true n-1 is the DF for lowess?